# How does a binary tree waste memory when stored as nodes and references?

Tags: binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm researching binary trees and came across this section describing storage methods.

It states that:

> In a language with records and references, binary trees are typically constructed by having a tree node structure which contains some data and references to its left child and its right child...
>
> ...This method of storing binary trees wastes a fair bit of memory, as the pointers will be null (or point to the sentinel) more than half the time...

Can someone demonstrate or further explain why this happens?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Methods_for_storing_binary_trees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical binary tree representation consists of the data associated with the node and two pointers to the left and right subtree respectively.

I think that with representation it is easy to realize that every node spends two pointers. Consequently, every tree of `n` nodes, spends a total of `2 x n` pointers in storage (for the pointers).

Now well, at the exception of the root, `n-1` nodes have a parent (that is an arc or edge). So, you really use `n-1` pointers of `2n` that you have (as explained in the previous paragraph).

That said, of a total of `2n` pointers, you always use `n-1`. The remaining `2n - (n-1) = n+1` are always set to `null`. So, no matter the tree topology, you always spend more space for storing `null` pointers than for storing tree arcs.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a full binary tree of height 3. It has 7 nodes. 4 of them have no children. 4/7 > 1/2.